# How to correctly write this "simple" T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I took a test with a bunch T-SQL exercises. I did well in all but one of them. I took a picture of it to find out later the correct answer. I don't consider myself an expert but I know my way around SQL. Yet, I cannot write what should be a not so hard query to come up with.

Here is the exercise:

[image: Query exercise]

I probably need to group by Name and Sum the price but I am still kinda lost. Help with this one! Thank you

Comment: `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  This is not particularly complicated.

Comment: It doesn't get *much* easier than this. One join and a simple aggregations, `Count()` and `Sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT 
  people.name, 
  sum(case when sales.fk_people is not null then 1 else 0) as total_sales,
  sum(coalesce(sales.price,0.0)) as total_amount
FROM people  
LEFT JOIN sales ON people.id = sales.fk_people
GROUP BY people.id
-- Could also be ORDER BY sum(coalesce(sales.price,0.0)) desc
ORDER BY people.id;
```

Comment: Since you are being more detailed (and rightfully so)... don't forget that there might be multiple John's working at the company.  So you would probably want to group by ID.  And then order by ID to get the correct non-alphabetical order.

Comment: Looks like the requested output is ordering by total_amount DESC.

Comment: @SamyCode will get additional points if he goes by this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple GROUP BY with a COUNT() and SUM(). The two tables will need to be joined as well:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as total_sales, sum(price) as total_amount
FROM people INNER JOIN sales ON people.id = sales.fk_people
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: I think a left join would be more correct -- what about a person that has no sales.

Comment: @Hogan question is to write SQL that gives the desired results pictured.  Inner join or left join would work as no data is pictured which would change the results either way.  I'd argue a left join could be worse as it would include a record in people w/o sales when the question only shows people with sales.

Comment: @Hogan It's a good point for OP to take into consideration as a real life example a LEFT OUTER JOIN may make more sense. I tend to use LEFT OUTER JOIN more often than INNER JOIN IRL.

Comment: @xQbert -- in my experience clients don't understand the subtle issues with left joins vs inner joins -- but they always expect to see the people who have 0 and then complain when it is not there.

Comment: I'd tend to agree but as this appears to be a test/quiz question.  book vs reality comes into play and book looks to be an inner join in this case; but as JNevill indicated; it's a good comment for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this

```
SELECT 
p.Name
,ISNULL(s.Total_Sales,0) AS Total_Sales
,ISNULL(s.Total_Amount,0) AS Total_Amount
FROM people p  
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    fk_people
    ,COUNT(*) AS Total_Sales
    ,SUM(Price) AS Total_Amount  
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY fk_people
) s ON p.ID = s.fk_people
```